# How to create a measure that would count only the last status based on last transaction date for each Person. Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

.pbix file can be found here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/61879ogf2slyavv/Count%20Open%20and%20Closed%20at%20Point%20of%20time.pbix?dl=0

I need to create two measures:

first would calculate only Open status for each Person based on last TransactionDate.

For example for claimID 5 we have three person6. The last TransactionDate has status `"Open"`. So count of `Open` for `Person6` would be 1 as of `12-31-2018`.  Same with Person5. We count it as 1 because status on last TransactionDate is "Open"

For Person3 the last status is "Closed". So we do not count this as open.  Same with Person2.

The same for `Closed`. If the last status on `transactionDate` is Closed then we count it as 1. Previous transactions we do not count.

For example `Person3` has status Closed on last `TransactionDate`. We count 1 for `Person3` as of `12-31-2018`

[image]

**CR7SMS** Thanks for your time. On a real data for some reason it does not work. 
Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create two columns which can then be summed up to get the Open Counts and the Closed Counts:

```
Open Rank = IF(RANKX(CALCULATETABLE(Claims,ALLEXCEPT(Claims,Claims[Person])),Claims[TransactionDate])=1 && Claims[Status]="Open",1,0)
Closed Rank = IF(RANKX(CALCULATETABLE(Claims,ALLEXCEPT(Claims,Claims[Person])),Claims[TransactionDate])=1 && Claims[Status]="Closed",1,0)
```

To get the counts of Open and Closed transactions, you can sum these columns up. This is done under the assumption that only the last transaction for each person matters. Everything else is ignored. Hope this helps.

Edit:

Adding Allselected:

```
Open Rank = IF(RANKX(CALCULATETABLE(Claims,ALLSELECTED(),ALLEXCEPT(Claims,Claims[Person])),Claims[TransactionDate])=1 && Claims[Status]="Open",1,0)
Closed Rank = IF(RANKX(CALCULATETABLE(Claims,ALLSELECTED(),ALLEXCEPT(Claims,Claims[Person])),Claims[TransactionDate])=1 && Claims[Status]="Closed",1,0)
```

Edit2:

```
Rank = 
VAR Max_date = Max(Claimants[TransactionDate])
VAR Min_date = Min(Claimants[TransactionDate])
VAR Rank1 =    RANKX(
        FILTER(CALCULATETABLE(
            Claimants
            ,ALLEXCEPT(Claimants,Claimants[ClaimNumber],Claimants[ClaimantID])),Claimants[TransactionDate]>=Min_date&&Claimants[TransactionDate]<=Max_date
                      ),Claimants[TransactionDate],,ASC,Dense
        )
Return Rank1
```

Tried this to see if the date dynamically affects the rank. It did not work for me, but with a little modification you might be able to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks. It works on example data, but does not work on real data. I am checking out. Thanks

Comment: I got a screenshot of the real data. Still cant get it why it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you remove the date filter and check? Maybe that's having an impact

Comment: If the date filter is not working properly, we may have to include a ALLSELECTED function to get the desired result

Comment: I have added an edit with allselected added, give that a try as well

Comment: Weird, but still does not bring correct result. Thinking what else could be

Comment: I am breaking down problem by pieces. If you want to take a look at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687376/how-to-create-dynamic-ranking-that-would-respond-by-date-slicer-in-power-bi