# How to create dynamic ranking that would respond by date slicer in Power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I simply need to create ranking column for each `ClaimantID` based on `TransactionDate` DESC.

example .pbix file can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dsnylng70t5a8i/Count%20Open%20and%20Closed%20at%20Point%20of%20time.pbix?dl=0

On a picture below I have two unique claims with TransactionDate.

So how can I RANK ClaimantID by TransactionDate in descending order?

I tried to create column Rank. But it does not give me desirable result:

```
Rank = 

    RANKX(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            Claimants
            ,ALLEXCEPT(Claimants,Claimants[ClaimantID])
                      ),Claimants[TransactionDate]
        )
```

[image]

**Result should look like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you Rank Calculation:

```
Rank = 

    RANKX(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            Claimants
            ,ALLEXCEPT(Claimants,Claimants[ClaimNumber],Claimants[ClaimantID])
                      ),Claimants[TransactionDate],,DESC,Dense
        )
```

Also currently in the table there are multiple transactions for the same date and you are summing up the rank. Change it to minimum of rank to get the correct results.

Comment: It works but it does not interact correctly with `TransactionDate` slicer. I think I need to come up with measure for that

Comment: This is where allselected might come in handy

Comment: Calculated columns are not dynamic, right? Cause in my logic it basically need to be recalculated every time TransactionDate slicer changes.

Comment: You can use variables I guess...Let me give it a try

Comment: I tried a calculation and added it as an edit in the previous question. Unfortunately I could not get it to work. You can use that and try and find the answer.